# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una cantidad ingresada por una persona a una cantidad específica ya existente de un atributo en una tabla mysql?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Estoy creando un inventario básico para un proyecto y tengo este método:

```
public void aumentar(){
    String nombrecon="";
    int cantau=0;
    nombrecon=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Nombre");
    int result=0;
    String cap="";
    String sql="SELECT * FROM inventario WHERE Nombre='"+nombrecon+"'";
    try {
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
        if(rs.next()){
            result=1;
            if(result==1){
        cantau=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese Cantidad"));
            }
        }else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto No Registrado");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArrayRUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Primero aparece un JOptionPane para ingresar el nombre de un producto, luego recorro los datos de la BD para validar que este producto exista, si es asi
aparece otro JOptionPane para ingresar la cantidad que deseo agregar.
¿Como podría capturar el atributo con el dato específico para agregarle la 
cantidad ingresada en el JOptionPane?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo agregarle 40 unidades mas a galletas. Ayuda por favor!!

Answer (score 0):

En pseudocódigo sería algo así;

1. Pedir nombre producto;
2. Conectar con la DB;
3. Comprobar que el producto existe;
4. Si existe;

   4.1. Pedir nueva cantidad;

   4.2. Conectar nuevamente con la Db;

   4.3. Actualizar registro con los nuevos datos;
5. Si no existe;

   5.1. Avisar de que no existe

   5.2. Salir del programa

Ahora te paso un ejemplo que programé yo para comprobar que funciona. Asegurate de cambiar todo lo necesario (nombre de la Db, usuario, contraseña, etc...)
Saludos!!

public class ActualizaTablaDB {

```
static String articulo;

public ActualizaTablaDB() {

    articulo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese nombre");
    if (isArticulo(articulo)) { // si existe, al siguiente paso
        String precio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa nuevo precio");
        Double _precio = Double.parseDouble(precio);
        actualizaArticulo(articulo, _precio);
    } 
}

/**
 * Si existe el artículo devuelve true
 * @param articulo
 * @return
 */
private static boolean isArticulo(String articulo) {
    boolean key = false; // por defecto no existe
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pruebas", "root", "");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE NOMBREARTICULO=?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, articulo);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.absolute(1)) { 
            key = true;
        }   
        else {
            System.out.println("Ese artículo no se encuentra en la base de datos");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return key;
}

/**
 * Actualiza el artículo
 * @param nombreArticulo
 * @param precio
 */
private void actualizaArticulo(String nombreArticulo, Double precio) {
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pruebas", "root", "");
        String sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTOS SET PRECIO=? WHERE NOMBREARTICULO=?";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDouble(1, precio);
        ps.setString(2, nombreArticulo);
        int retorno = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(retorno);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Test
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ActualizaTablaDB();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Busque un buen rato y no encontré una manera de editar una cantidad e ir acumulando, así que lo que se me ocurre es simplemente consultar cuanto hay actualmente antes de editar y luego sumarlo al nuevo ingreso, si alguien conoce otra forma seria bueno aportarla.

```
public void editar() {
        String columna = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre del atributo");
        String cantidad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cantidad a ingresar al inventario");
        Integer aux =Integer.valueOf(buscar(columna)); // cantidad antigua en la BD
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = getConexion();

        String sql = "UPDATE inv SET cantidad=? WHERE nombre=? ";
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, Integer.valueOf(cantidad)+aux); //enviamos la cantidad total
            ps.setString(2, columna);
            ps.execute();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Stack.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    public String buscar(String nombre) {
        String cantidadAnterior="";
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = getConexion();
        String sql = "SELECT cantidad FROM inv WHERE nombre=?";//buscamos la cantidad que ya existe

        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, nombre);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                cantidadAnterior=rs.getString("cantidad"); 
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Stack.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return cantidadAnterior;

    }
```